# How to make an array of bits?

Tags: c, bit, bit-fields

I want to make an array of int bit fields where each int has one bit, meaning that all of the numbers will be 1 or 0, how can I code that?

I tried

```
struct bitarr {
    int arr : 1[14];
};
```

but that doesn't compile and I don't think that this is the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do array of these bits. Instead, create single 16-bit variable for your bits, then instead of accessing it as `i[myindex]` you can access it as `bitsVariable & (1 << myindex)`.

To set bit, you can use:

```
bitsVariable |= 1 << myindex;
```

To clear bit, you can use:

```
bitsVariable &= ~(1 << myIndex);
```

To check bit, you can use:

```
if (bitsVariable & (1 << myIndex)) {
    //Bit is set
} else {
    //Bit is not set
}
```